# Conflict query with auth since i added a relation with a model

Tags: cakephp

I have a User Model which is linked by a relation to a Company Model .
It works perfectly . The problem is since i added the relation , when i want to be loged, the query build a query with Company .

I don't want to use a company model for the login action .

When i click on the submit button, this is what i get :

Database Error

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Company.user_id' in 'on clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`town_id`, `User`.`company_id`, `User`.`test_id`, `Company`.`id`, `Company`.`name` FROM `users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `companies` AS `Company` ON (`Company`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `User`.`username` = 'CREAZ' AND `User`.`password` = '04fb76559109f9bbb69fc6805fccedb6a3b79982' ORDER BY `User`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

company_id doesn't exist for the users table, it's only for companies table, that's why it doesn't work .

Do i need to change the Auth part in my appController or change something in the action login of UsersController ?

UserController (login action) :

```
public function login(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        if($this->Auth->login()){
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()); 
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash("Votre login ou votre mot de passe ne correspond pas","notif",array('type'=>'error'));
        }
    }
}
```

login view

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Se connecter</h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('username',array('label'=>"Login")); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('password',array('label'=>"Mot de passe")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Se connecter'); ?>
```

AppController :

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller{
    public $helpers = array('Text','Form','Html','Session','Cache');
    public $components = array('Session','Auth');

    function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login','admin'=>false);
        $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');

        if(!isset($this->request->params['prefix'])){
            $this->Auth->allow(); 
        }

        if(isset($this->request->params['prefix']) && $this->request->params['prefix'] == 'admin'){
            $this->layout = 'admin';
        }       
    }

    function isAuthorized($user){
        if(!isset($this->request->params['prefix'])){
            return true;
        }

        $roles = array(
            'admin' => 10,
            'user'  => 5
        ); 

        if(isset($roles[$this->request->params['prefix']])){
            $lvlAction = $roles[$this->request->params['prefix']];
            $lvlUser   = $roles[$user['role']]; 
            if($lvlUser >= $lvlAction){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false; 
            }
        }

        return false; 
    }
}
```

User Model :

```
<?php 

class User extends AppModel{

    public $actsAs = array('Containable'); 

    public $hasOne = array(
        'Company' => array(
            'className' => 'Company',
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );

    public $recursive = -1; 

    public $order = 'User.id DESC';

    public $validate = array(

        'username' => array(

            'rule'       => 'isUnique',

            'allowEmpty' => false,

            'message'    => "Ce nom d'utilisateur est déja pris"

        ),

        'password' => array(

            'rule'       => 'notEmpty',

            'message'    => "Vous ne pouvez pas entrer de mot de pase"

        )

    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array()){

        if(!empty($this->data['User']['password'])){

            $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);

        }

        return true; 

    }

}
```

Company Model

```
<?php 

class Company extends AppModel{

 public $hasMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
        'dependent' => false
    ));

}

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the relationship between User and Company works perfectly? The error looks like you have not implemented the relationship in the User model correctly because Cakephp is trying to JOIN on the wrong column names. You could share the User model's code showing the relationship to Company.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. Yes it works, i mean for the relation . It's only for authentification, i just need that CakePHP uses only the table user . I edited my post with User and Company model .

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the User model to use $belongsTo, and not the $hasOne

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Company' => array(
        'className' => 'Company',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id'
    );
```

Comment: I fixed it, it was because i had to add 'foreignKey' => 'id' in User Model .

Comment: i have company_id in users table and id, name in companies .